# ¿Porque al actualizar un objeto de mi estado se modifica tambien la lista de donde se obtuvo?

Tags: flutter, dart

Uso la estructura de estados ViewModel (Similar a Jetpack Compose) en flutter y tengo lo siguiente:

- Una clase de estados donde tengo como un estado una lista de objetos de tipo TemplateVenusModel.
- Un estado donde tengo un objeto de tipo TemplateVenusModel que guarda la plantilla actual seleccionada llamado templateVenusSelected.

El objeto TemplateVenusModel, tiene una lista de DataTempalte (Otro modelo).

Funcionalidad esperada:

El estado de templateVenusSelected se actualiza mediante un Autocomplete, este Autocomplate se pobla con la lista de TemplatesVenusModel.
En el UI, tengo un ListView que se alimenta de los DataTemplate del objeto templateVenusSelected. Este listview, tiene un boton para eliminar el index actual de la lista de DataTemplate del templateVenusSelected.

Problema:
Al eliminar un DataTemplate del templateVenusSelected, tambien se elimina de la lista padre. Es decir, si elimino un DataTemplate, en el UI todo funciona bien, es mas, al cambiar desde el Autocompelte a otro TemplateVenusModel, se settea normal la lista de DataTemplate en el ListView. El problema es que si, selecciono de nuevo la TemplateVenusModel del que elimine el DataTemplate, me encuentro con que tambien se elimina de la lista padre.

Codigo de la clase del estado:

```
class CreateReportState {
  bool loadingScreen=true;
  List<TemplateVenusModel> templates=[];

  bool typeReportClose= false;
  int typeReportSelected =2;
  TemplateVenusModel? templateVenusSelected ;
  List<TextEditingController> controllersDataReq = [];
  List<FocusNode> focusDataReq = [];

  TextEditingController controllerDescription = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerResolution = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerIncident = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerTitle = TextEditingController();

  List<CatalogModel> typesError = [];
  List<CatalogModel> typesOrigin = [];
  int currentTypeError = 0;
  int currentTypeOrigin = 2;

  bool openedFromIAButton = false;
}
```

Codigo del UI (Lista de DataTemplate):

```
ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: height*0.01,),
      itemCount: state.templateVenusSelected!.dataRequired!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        TemplateDataRequiredModel dataRequired = state.templateVenusSelected!.dataRequired!.elementAt(index);
        return _RowDataReport(
          indexDataList: index,
          state: state,
          viewModel: viewModel,
          dataRequired: dataRequired,
          controller: state.controllersDataReq.elementAt(index),
          focusController: state.focusDataReq.elementAt(index),
          onExitFocus: (){
            viewModel.replaceDataInDescAndRes(
                data: state.controllersDataReq.elementAt(index).text,
                alias: dataRequired.infoDataRequired?.alias??"",
                currentDescription: state.controllerDescription.text,
                currentResolution: state.controllerResolution.text
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
```

Codigo del UI (Row donde esta el boton de eliminar):

```
class _RowDataReport extends StatelessWidget {
  const _RowDataReport({super.key, required this.state, required this.viewModel, required this.dataRequired, required this.controller,  this.focusController, this.onExitFocus, required this.indexDataList});

  final int indexDataList ;
  final TemplateDataRequiredModel dataRequired;
  final CreateReportState state;
  final CreateReportViewModel viewModel;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FocusNode? focusController;
  final Function()? onExitFocus;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: InputBasic(
            labelText: dataRequired.infoDataRequired?.description,
            controller: controller,
            focus: focusController,
            onExitFocus: onExitFocus,
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            viewModel.removeDataRequiredToList(indexDataList);
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

ViewModel para eliminar el index:

```
  void removeDataRequiredToList(int index){
    notify(RemoveDataToListRequired(index));
  }
```

Event:

```
class RemoveDataToListRequired extends ViewEvent {
    int index;
    RemoveDataToListRequired(this.index):super("RemoveDataToListRequired");
}
```

El listener del evento:

```
  @override
  void notify(ViewEvent event) {
    switch (event.runtimeType) { 
      case RemoveDataToListRequired:
        _handleRemoveDataToListRequired(event as RemoveDataToListRequired);
        break; 
    }
  }

  void _handleRemoveDataToListRequired(RemoveDataToListRequired event) {
    // print(event.index);
    // print(state.templateVenusSelected?.dataRequired?.length);
    // print(state.templates.where((element) => element.idTemplate==state.templateVenusSelected?.idTemplate).first.dataRequired?.length);
    setState(() {
      state.templateVenusSelected?.dataRequired?.removeAt(event.index);
    });
  }
```